# Exact system actions when we use this commands

Tags: command-line

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS (64 bit Linux).

I want to know what exactly the system does when we use the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep -i ^rc
sudo dpkg -l | grep -i ^rc | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs dpkg --purge
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg -l
```

list packages

```
| grep -i ^rc
```

that start (`^`) with `rc`.  'rc' means that the package has been removed, but that there are still configuration files on the system.

```
| cut -d " " -f 3
```

"cut" at the space, select only the 3rd field (`-f 3`; we are counting spaces and there are 2 in front of the packagename).

```
| xargs dpkg --purge
```

and purge it. Example without purging:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep -i ^rc 
rc  linux-image-5.0.0-7-generic           5.0.0-7.8                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-modules-5.0.0-7-generic         5.0.0-7.8                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-7-generic   5.0.0-7.8                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP


$ sudo dpkg -l | grep -i ^rc | cut -d " " -f 3 
linux-image-5.0.0-7-generic
linux-modules-5.0.0-7-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-7-generic
```

Comment: Is `sudo` needed? Does `grep`’s `-i` change anything? But that’s the *second* column… What does removing every `rc` package do to the system, is it harmful/a good idea/unnecessary/…?

Comment: @dessert 3rd when counting spaces. sudo: the last part probably does. Have not tried the purge :+

Comment: `sudo` not needed for `dpkg -l`.

Comment: ah but it probably carries over to the purge if its within the 15 min timeframe ;) Oh and to the downvoter: please explain what is wrong about this? The sudo is part of the OP not mine :+

Comment: Just a doubt... How can we be absolutely sure to not erase something really important with these commands?

Comment: Cuz of the `rc`  ;)